# How do you intercept USB printer error messages when using StartDoc()/EndDoc()?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, printer-control-language

I hope someone can point me in the correct direction regarding the
printing problem I am having below:

Setup:
Win CE 5.0 
Trying to print from a custom application.

I have written a very simple printing class in my application that
uses the pcl driver and prints to a HP USB printer. The printing
aspect is fine under normal circumstances, but I cannot see an obvious
way to handle error conditions such as no paper in printer etc.

I am doing something like this (general error checking and other
details removed for clarity):

```
// Get a DC to the printer. If printer isn't powered this will fail -
can print error stating "printer not found" or similar
hdcPrinter = CreateDC(@"pcl.dll", @"PCL Inkjet", @"LPT2:", ref mode);


// Signal the start of a document
StartDoc(hdcPrinter, &docInfo)
// Signal the start of a page
StartPage(hdcPrinter)

// Prepare the page to print/formatting etc

// Finished preparing the page
EndPage(hdcPrinter)

// This is the only page we are printing this time
EndDoc(hdcPrinter)

// Return the printer DC to the system as we are finished with it now.
DeleteDC(hdcPrinter);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Shilpa

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure get DC succeeds even if the printer is out of paper, jammed, or otherwise not ready?

Once you start the print job, it isn't your problem if the printer runs into a problem. At that point, the OS is supposed to interact with the user and let them know that there is a problem, restart the job if necessary, etc...